# Class design: How to implement RAII ressource management for Log-Listener class

Tags: c++, class-design, raii

EDIT: Alright, the question does not seem to be suitable for the platform as there is no real technical background here. No problem (really, no sarcasm), I will look somewhere else for advice. Thanks anyway.

I have a question purely about class design: Assume, we want to attach LogListener objects to a central managing host (Host class in the minimal example. We cannot change this implementation as it comes from a foreign codebase).

One crucial thing to ensure is to detach from the Host as soon as our listening task is done. For this to accomplish I want to call the detach method of the host from the destructor of some class in our codebase (current options for this task are the simplified classes Manager{A,B,C}).

My question now is concerned on how to design this. I have listed three options of which I currently opt for the first one as it is the most convenient to use for the moment but it violates the single responsibility principle (managing the Host-connection and listen to the logs). Further Listener derivations do not benefit from the connection management.

Do you have any advice for which way to go? I am pretty sure, I missed Option 4, 5, ... If you have some further ideas, those are very welcome!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <set>
#include <utility>

// Simplified base class for the Listener interface
// ================================================
class Listener {
public:
    virtual void listen(const std::string& msg) = 0;
};

// Simplified implementation of a Host, storing logging listeners
// ==============================================================
class Host {
public:
    void attach(Listener* listener) { m_coll.insert(listener); };
    void detach(Listener* listener) { m_coll.erase(listener); };
    void call(const std::string& msg) { for(auto* L : m_coll) { L->listen(msg); }}
private:
    std::set<Listener*> m_coll;
};

static Host globalHost{};


class DerivedListener : public Listener {
public:
    void listen (const std::string& msg) override { std::cout << "Two!\n"; }
};

// Solution 1. Violates single responsibility, but has no "lifetime issues"
// Manager + Listener in one class
// ========================================================================
class ManagerA : public Listener {
public:
    ManagerA() { globalHost.attach(this); }
    ~ManagerA() { globalHost.detach(this); }
    void listen (const std::string& msg) override { std::cout << "One!\n"; }
};

// Solution 2. Has lifetime issues. Takes a raw-pointer to the listener but
// what if the managed pointer is deallocated during lifetime of the Manager?
// Moreover it has Optional semantics - the pointer may be NULL but then it
// cannot be attached as Host does not tolerate nullptrs.
// ==========================================================================
class ManagerB {
public:
    explicit ManagerB (Listener* listener) : m_ptr{listener} { if (m_ptr) globalHost.attach(m_ptr); }
    ~ManagerB() { globalHost.detach(m_ptr); }
private:
    Listener* m_ptr;
};

// Solution 3: Takes ownership of the managed ressource -> No lifetime issues
// but must implement Optional-Semantics because the internal ressource is
// empty after the claim. The claim again is neccessary as the caller needs
// access to the managed object and make independent of the manager.
class ManagerC {
public:
    explicit ManagerC (std::unique_ptr<Listener> listener) : m_ptr{std::move(listener)}
        { if (m_ptr) globalHost.attach(m_ptr.get()); }
    ~ManagerC() { globalHost.detach(m_ptr.get()); }
    std::unique_ptr<Listener> claim() { globalHost.detach(m_ptr.get()); return std::exchange(m_ptr, nullptr); }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Listener> m_ptr;
};

int main() {
    ManagerA mA{};

    DerivedListener listenerB;
    ManagerB mB{&listenerB};

    ManagerC mC{std::make_unique<DerivedListener>()};
    auto listenerC = mC.claim();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Several approaches are possible. This is really asking which one's the best; however  that would be a matter of opinion, since everyone has their own definition of what "best" means, and asking for opinions is not an appropriate question for Stackoverflow. Can you reframe your question so that instead of "advice" it's asking a concrete, technical question that can be answered with facts or citations?

Comment: not sure what you want, but imo it looks like a function to fetch data is all you need?

Comment: 4: `template<class T> class Manager { private: T listener; };`

Comment: I don't understand why you say that options #2 and #3 need to support the pointer being/becoming null, when option #1 doesn't support anything like that. Why not just use option #3 *without* the `claim` function and the `if (m_ptr)`?

Comment: Where is  the invocation of `host::call`? How do you get notified if a specific listener was `listen`ed?! Is there any parallelization/concurrency or just linear execution?! Though the question is long, it doesn't provide necessary details for a proper answer.